# replace ui-select style to original style

Tags: css, angularjs

I have two dropdown menus on http://www.jiyubi.com/#/tour_package/home

The left one is applied  `angular-ui-select/dist/select.min.css`

But I'd like the right one style.

What is the quickest get it?

Because it seems angular-ui-select will modify the DOM element.

I don't know which approach can make the left one has the same style as the right one.

[image]

[image]

Current style `http://www.jiyubi.com/#/tour_package/home`

This is desired style `http://52.196.210.40:3000/portal/package_home.html`

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a bit more context?  I'm not quite sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you show us a link with the desired select style?

Comment: @mrlew i updated the post, pls see the bottom of the post for accessing the page , thank you

Comment: You don't have access to the css files in both cases? What css is to be replaced with which. The more  precise the question, the clearer the answer, too. Otherwise pure quess is there.

Comment: What credible and/or official sources can there be, when you have not included any code in the question itself? Or indicated what component you're using for the select you want to use?

Answer (score 5):

angular-ui-select has three built in themes:

quote from [1]:

> ui-select has the following themes:
>
> - bootstrap inspired from the popular bootstrap framework.
> - select2 inspired from select2 jQuery widget
> - selectize inspired from selectize jQuery widget
>
> Themes can be set at a global level using a provider:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.select']);

app.config(function(uiSelectConfig) {
   uiSelectConfig.theme = 'bootstrap';
});
```

> or as a property on the select element like:

```
<ui-select ng-model="animal.id" theme="bootstrap">
    ...
</ui-select>
```

If these ready made styles aren't either inspired of correct framework or otherwise do not please your eye, you can always make your own css about the classes that angular-ui-select uses, place there desired style and use !important with the css definitions to overwrite the originals.

```
.style.not.pleasing.eye {
    something: sth_new !important;
}
```

---

**My sources:**

[1] https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select